# Excel Matrix Assignment by Referring to a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I am trying to construct a 2x2 matrix dependent on values in some cells (say B1). The code shall take the reference and make some mathematical manipulations, then assign this value to a new cell.

```
Sub matrix2()

    Dim matrix(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String
    
    k1 = Cells(1, 2).Value
    
    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 2
            k = (-1) ^ (i + j)
            matrix(i, j) = "=B1*" & k
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Range("D1:E2") = matrix
    
End Sub
```

In the end, I get what I want but I need to go to each cell and press Enter to convert them in a real value. What I should get here is a matrix dependent on the value in B1. When I change B1, the values in the matrix will automatically change.

Is there any way to make it happen more easily? Because, I will be dealing with 40x40 matrices in the end, and I don't want to go over 1600 cells and press Enter.

Comment: Why not just use `k1*k`?

Comment: If I use k1, I cannot refer to B1 again.

Comment: Why not? `k1` is B1. Use `worksheet change` to make it dynamic.

Comment: I made a quick search on this. If I am not mistaken, when the cell value is changed, the macro will be run automatically to update. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you, that was eventually what I was looking for. This solves my problem. I needed to keep reference to couple the matrices with optimization solver. By this option, it will automatically run macro for all the time, and do whatever I want.

Comment: I don't know why but when I make it Worksheet Change, it freezes my Excel and eventually leads to a crash.

Comment: You are probably not disabling events so that whenever you change a cell you cause an endless loop. Post a new question with your code if you can't resolve it, but you'll need an `application.enableevents=false` at the start (or just limit your code to run only when B1 is changed).

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't forget to re-enable events at the end.

Comment: I used rather a different approach and limited to work if the range of cells are changed. But without your idea, I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is going to be helpfull right now, but maybe in the (near) future. With the new [`MAKEARRAY()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/makearray-function-b80da5ad-b338-4149-a523-5b221da09097) function you could do this outside of VBA with relative ease:

[image]

Formula in `D3`:

```
=MAKEARRAY(2,2,LAMBDA(i,j,B1*(-1^(i+j))))
```

Comment: Thank you, but my Excel does not support MAKEARRAY() function.

Comment: @nicomedian So why not just array-enter `=B1*{1,-1;-1,1}` over a 2x2 range of cells?

Comment: That's surely the easiest thing. My aim is to do ultimately different thing, but to implement that, I need the approach I asked. I will be dealing with hundreds of things which would be waste of time to define by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a variant-array - not a string-array

Try this:

```vb
Sub Matrix2()
Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 2) as Variant 'instead of String
    
    k1 = Cells(1, 2).Value
    
    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 2
            k = (-1) ^ (i + j)
            arr(i, j) = "=B1*" & k
        Next
    Next
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 1).Resize(2, 2).Formula = arr
end sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed.

Comment: I have the feeling that you are using some strange characters - if I copy your code from the question - it doesn't work. But if I retype everything, it works ... I add my code to the answer, please copy, paste and try this on your machine.

Comment: It perfectly worked!

Comment: So the problem is the definition of `matrix`- you used a string-array, but it has to be variant: `Dim matrix(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant`

Comment: You are right, I also tried that and worked perfectly fine. Thank you.